# Set ZIndex On Parent Content Presenter in a Trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, wpf-controls

I have an ItemsControl which has a Canvas as it's ItemsPanel, the items are simple Borders, the details of the Borders are databound from a view model, data like X,Y Width, Height, Colour etc. I soon realised that even though I could bind most data like the size and colour to the border item itself I had to bind the point data and ZIndex in the ItemsControl Container Style, I believe this is because these properties pertains only to that ItemContainer which is a ContentPresenter:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style>
             <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Metrics.Ordinate.X}"/>
             <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Metrics.Ordinate.Y}"/>
             <Setter Property="Canvas.ZIndex" Value="{Binding ZIndex}"/>
       </Style>
 </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Everything has been working as needed up to now.  When the user was hovering over the borders I was using a trigger on mouse over to change the background colour but because the UI is already so dependant upon colours we decided that for the hover we wanted the borders to increase in size.  So I added a scale transform instead:

```
 <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
     <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding SelectedTemplate.StandardBrush}"></Setter>-->
         <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
               <Setter.Value>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
                </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
 </Trigger>
```

Now the problem is that I need to increase the ZIndex of that single border in the trigger as well so that as it grows it is not clipped by its nearby fellow items.  I was searching on how to set the parent item (ContentPresenter) in XAML in a trigger and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158832/how-to-set-a-trigger-on-a-child-to-a-parent-property).  That looks perfect except that there is no Name on the content presenter to reference it with, it is a repeated control and I cannot fathom how I can reference it within XAML.

Is this possible within a trigger or am I best looking for a different approach, either one not relying solely upon XAML or maybe a change to my ItemsControl?

Many thanks in advance.

Paul

**Edit**

Adding the panel template:

```
 <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <local:AutoSizeCanvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

AutoCanvas is a custom control the derives from Canvas which overrides the measure override so it plays ball living inside a scrollviewer, that is the only difference to a standard Canvas.

**Edit**

Just to add that I'm using data templates for the bound items as some borders need to contain slightly different items within them, David's current answer below does work, on mouse over the ZIndex is increased, the problem is that all items that are hovered over have their ZIndex increased so if the mouse goes over an item that is meant to be at the back then it is raised to the top, also this seems very slow.  The solution does work but not quite in this scenario as it is doing a blanket setting on all items, not just the one type of border that needs the trigger.  In essence I have a seating plan which I get the visual data from another application and have to use it as is.  The plan has zones, blocks, rows and seats, It is only the seats that I want this trigger to occur for.

Hope that's clear.

Comment: could you add the itemsControl's template? (specifically, the ItemsPanelTemplate to see how you manage to have a Canvas as an Item presenter.) as well as the code behind managing the items added if you can.

Comment: @David Just added the panel template.

Comment: ok, I was actually after the AutoSizeCanvas implementation. (I'm trying to reproduce your issue, but using a canvas as an itemsPresenter is quite uncommon and needs quite a bit of code behind to run. Kind of a big thing to repro :-/ )

Comment: Yeah, I admit, it is an unusual thing, I'm kind of tied with the data I have a need of performance (target machines will not be too powerful and a lot of items have to be rendered.) My initial approach for the seating plan used nested canvas' so your approach below would have worked but the performance was horrendous and I had to go with a single canvas with everything bound and using ZIndex to control the "Container" nature of the visual appearance.

Comment: woah... You'll need to include a lot more code for people to understand your problem there. This really is a complicated issue. If you can, copy/paste the entire xaml and maybe some code behind so that we can really picture what you are trying to achieve. As far as I'm concerned, I'm lost with the explanation you gave in your edit 2 :-/

Comment: @David, yeah I was hoping to not have to go into too much detail, was hoping for a miracle answer on how to set a template parent property in XAML, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure that you need the ContentPresenter's ZIndex to be increased and not just the Border's ZIndex?

if so, you do not have many options there. The best I can see is to setup the trigger directly in the itemsPresenter's style. This way you don't have to try to find the border's parent (wich I think is impossible to do just in xaml anyway)

so you'd end up with something like this:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Metrics.Ordinate.X}"/>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Metrics.Ordinate.Y}"/>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.ZIndex" Value="{Binding ZIndex}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.ZIndex" Value="1000"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: arf... I haven't actually tested this. I'll test and try to figure this out then.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried but it cannot build because the style doesn't have a trigger property of mouse over.

Comment: have you set the TargetType on your style correctly? I have no trouble building (but I must admit I cannot run it for now, still writing the code behind)

Comment: You were correct, I added the target type on the style and it did build and work, however I have hit another problem with this approach, I've appended to my question.  Thank you.

Comment: @Dave I have added an answer where I solved the problem in Code Behind instead of pure XAML, it is not quite what I wanted and it is painfully slow so I may have to abandon (setting Canvas.ZIndex is apparently a slow operation), thank you very much for your effort and the answer you provided which was correct for the initial question. +1

Comment: In the end I abandoned because of performance issues, I just used the trigger on the border for the scale transform but toned it down so the items didn't overlap, not perfect but it's better than bad performance.  Thank you for your help, I've accepted your answer as it did answer my initial question rather well.

Answer (score 0):

David's answer is correct for my original question before I provided additional detail and is a perfectly good answer, sadly it did not work in my peculiar scenario.

I managed to solve the problem with code behind for my datatemplate border:

The XAML for the template :

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Seat}">
    <Border CornerRadius="3" Width="{Binding Metrics.Size.Width}" Height="{Binding Metrics.Size.Height}" BorderThickness="2" MouseEnter="MouseEnter" MouseLeave="MouseLeave">
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="ZoomTransform" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
        </Border.RenderTransform>
        <Border.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding LeftClickCommand}"/>
            <MouseBinding Gesture="RightClick" Command="{Binding RightClickCommand}"/>
        </Border.InputBindings>
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding PriceBorderColour}"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Template.StandardBrush}"></Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding SelectedTemplate.StandardBrush}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Plan.EditModel.EditEnabled}" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Pen"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
        <Viewbox>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ObjectLabel.Text}" Foreground="{Binding ObjectLabel.FontColour}"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

And the Code Behind:

```
public partial class VisualDataTemplates : ResourceDictionary
{
    private Int32 _originalZIndex;
    private const Double _scaleSize = 1.5;
    private const Double _standardScaleSize = 1;

    public VisualDataTemplates()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected void MouseEnter(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Border border = sender as Border;
        ContentPresenter presenter = border.TemplatedParent as ContentPresenter;

        _originalZIndex = Canvas.GetZIndex(presenter);
        Canvas.SetZIndex(presenter, DisplayOrders.FrontItem);

        SetTransform(border, _scaleSize);
    }

    protected void MouseLeave(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Border border = sender as Border;
        ContentPresenter presenter = border.TemplatedParent as ContentPresenter;
        Canvas.SetZIndex(presenter, _originalZIndex);

        SetTransform(border, _standardScaleSize);

    }

    private void SetTransform(Border border, Double value)
    {
        ScaleTransform transform = border.RenderTransform as ScaleTransform;
        transform.ScaleX = transform.ScaleY = value;
    }
}
```

The only problem I have now is that it is slow as hell so I may have to abandon this idea entirely and find another visual effect for the hover.

If anyone else has any better ideas then please provide.

Thanks

Paul